# How to define properties with a Proxy

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class with a Proxy in it which looks like this:

```
export class Row<T extends ModelItems> {

  private _row: T = <T>{}

  public constructor(rowItems?: T) {
    if (rowItems) { this._row = rowItems }
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get: function (target, prop) {
        return (<any>target)[prop] || target._row[prop] || ''
      }
      /* set(): snipped */
  }
}
```

When I do this:

```
interface User {
    id: number
    first: string
    last: string
    username: string
}

let row = new Row<User>({/* My object */})
```

How can I get it so that when I type `row` I get a list of items that are defined in the `User` interface. Right now all that gets suggested are the actual methods/properties that are in the root of the object.

I have tried this:

```
export interface Row<T extends ModelItems> {
  [key: string]: T 
}
```

This however doesn't seem to help at all other than telling me that my methods aren't defined propertly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want an instance of `Row<T>` to also be a `T` itself; is that right?  TypeScript won't let you do something like `class Row<T> implements T`, nor will it easily infer that itself.  Instead you could do something like the following:

```
export class _Row<T> {
 // ... your definition above
}
// Row type alias
export type Row<T extends ModelItems> = _Row<T> & T;
// Row value alias
export const Row = _Row as {
  new <T>(rowItems?: T): Row<T>
  prototype: _Row<{}>
}
```

This behaves more or less the same at runtime, but now TypeScript will understand that an instance of `Row<T>` has all the properties that `T` has:

```
declare const u: User;
let row = new Row(u); // inferred as Row<User>
row.username // string
```

---

If you are trying to represent something different, like a `Row<T>` behaves like something with all the keys of `T` but with possibly-empty-string properties, you could replace the `// Row type alias` with this instead:

```
// Row type alias
export type Row<T extends ModelItems> = _Row<T> &
  {[K in keyof T]: T[K] | ''};
```

And verify that it behaves as you expect:

```
declare const u: User;
let row = new Row(u); // inferred as Row<User>
row.id // number || ''
```

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to do this? I don't what to have to do `item instanceof _Row` I would like to do `item instanceof Row` and `new Row` not `new _Row`

Comment: You _can_ can do `item instanceof Row` and `new Row`.  Try it out.

Comment: Huh... Strange. I have `public get length` in the class `_Row`, and when I did this: `item instance of Row && item.length > 0` it was saying that length didn't exist on `Row`

Comment: I also have a constructor that looks like this: `public constructor(rows: Row<I>[] | Row<I>)` If I pass an item that is an `instanceof Row` I get an error, if I pass an item that is an `instanceof _Row` I don't get an error. Error: `else if (i instanceof Row) {this._items = new DataSet(i)}` Not an error: else if (i instanceof _Row) {this._items = new DataSet(i)}

Comment: And the error is: `Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Row<this> | Row<this>[]'`

Comment: Ah, the type guard narrowing with `instanceof` looks at the `prototype` property of the constructor, which I didn't specify.  See edit above; I added a `prototype: _Row<{}>` property, so that should fix some of those issues.  Does that help?

Comment: Looks like that fixes it! I'm still making sure it is working with all uses. So far it looks like an acceptable answer!